# Rails interaction with database in services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, models

Today i had a conversation with my colleague. We discussed database interactions in services. Is it a good practice to create some table rows in services if it needs some complex logic(operations) to be done before creation, like that:

```
class UserService
  def create(some_params)
    some_attributes = ...
    # some logic before creation
    ...
    User.create(some_attributes)
  end
end
```

He said that services should only prepare data before creation and should be called inside of a model like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.prepare_and_create(params)
    result = UserPreparationService.new(params).prepare
    create(result)
  end
end
```

Could you please answer what way is right or better?